# Force input box tooltip/title to appear

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, I'm not using jQuery and I wonder if there's any way to FORCE an input box tooltip to appear. 
(I want to use this tooltip to tell user to enter another username and/or the password is not acceptable.)

```js
function change(){
    if (document.getElementById('myTextField').value.length < 5){
        alert('show the tooltip in this case ');
    }
}
```

```css
#myTextField{
    
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myTextField"/>
<input type="submit" id="myButton" value="click me !" onclick="change()"/>
```

Comment: nice... but.. Which is the question? do you have code to share?

Comment: Just added the code , it's a react app.

Comment: if you make a fiddle, I may help you

Comment: Snippet added to the post @francesco

Comment: do you mean the tooltip for the `title` html attribute or are you using another library for your tooltips, i'm sorry can you explain this?

Comment: Use pseudo elements? Do `content: attr(data-tooltip);` and add a `data-tooltip` attribute to the html element.

Comment: I want a tooltip for the input box to appear, so the user knows that an input with length < 5 was entered in the box.

Comment: @Roope: can you add it to the code snippet ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh I don't have the time to write the code right now, sorry. But anyway, you should google "css tooltip" and you'll find out that those use `:after` or `:before` to make it happen, and those use the css `content` property for the tooltip text, and then you can either hardcode the text to that `content` property and use multiple different classes for different texts, or then use the `content: attr();` that I presented earlier and just change the attribute in the html element. But as I mentioned, google "css tooltip" and you should be able to figure it out. At least try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As also mentioned by @Roope in the comment above, you can play with the `data` element and the CSS pseudo-elements.

The `data` elements are accessible by both: javascript and CSS. 
But in CSS (so far) you can only access it in the `content` property of the pseudo-elements `::after` and `::before`, that's enough to manage the tooltip (almost) only in CSS

P.S. the code is tested only on Chrome (the transition property could need prefix on other browsers)

```js
function change(){
    document.getElementById('myTooltip').style.opacity = '1';
    if (document.getElementById('myTextField').value.length < 5){
        document.getElementById('myTooltip').setAttribute('data-tooltip', 'tooltip text');
    }
}

function keyPress(){
    document.getElementById('myTooltip').style.opacity = '0';
}
```

```css
#myTooltip {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

#myTooltip:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 180%;
  width:160px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

#myTooltip:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 155%;
  left: 85px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<span id="myTooltip"></span>
<input type="text" id="myTextField" onkeyup="keyPress()"/>
<input type="submit" id="myButton" value="click me !" onclick="change()"/>
```